# Understanding Likert-scale data and calculating composite score

Tags: survey, likert, composite

I have conducted a questionnaire without much knowing about Likert. Now I realized that I have both Likert-scale data and Likert-type questions. I think I can look at their descriptive statistics through different methods: mean and standard deviation for Likert-scale data and median and frequency for Likert-type.

I am not good at how to calculate a composite score for the Likert-scale data either. I have answers for level of preference (5 items) of different adaptation tools regarding three climate change impacts (heatwave, flood, drought) separately. There are two groups of options in all three: concrete vs green. The green options can also be divided into three categories based on the scale (building, street, city).

So I want to understand if I can calculate a composite score to understand the general tendency on scales based on the answers. I am open to any kind of suggestion regarding analyzing the tendency over the inquired options by combining the answers.

Comment: The mean and standard deviation of a Likert scale are not well-defined. Likert scales are ordinal, rather than interval scales; what this means is that addition or subtraction on a Likert scale are not well-defined.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What's your goal here -- what do you want to predict?

Comment: I strongly recommend Richard McElreath's book *Statistical Rethinking*, which includes a great section on how to model variables on an ordinal scale (e.g. Likert scales). He also posts all of his lectures online on his YouTube page.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was really good and motivating to see replies in a short time. The book seems quite interesting, I am impressed by the introduction referring Golem.

My goal is to understand if I can make an analysis among these to extract a possible general tendency toward concrete vs green options. And also to see the preference regarding green options at different scales.

So I have the first question, asking how much the respondent prefer suggested options against drought, and then the same question with different options for flood and heatwave as the third.

Comment: What is common among the suggested options is they can be categorized as concrete vs. green. And the green ones can be subdivided into three scales. However, the number of suggested options are not same. 5 for the first one (3 green (1 city, 1 street, 1 building), 2 concrete), 6 for the second (4 green (1 city, 1 street, 1 building, 1 city-street), 2 concrete), 8 for the last (6 green (2 city, 2 street, 2 building), 2 concrete). I guess it is quite complicated but I want to know what is the best I can extract and infer.